# How to install PHP soap extension on Alpine 3.6

Tags: php, linux, soap, alpine-linux

I'm having issues trying to install and enable the PHP soap extension. I'm running the base image `php:7.2-fpm-alpine3.6` inside a Docker container that has instructions like below in the `Dockerfile`. It's unclear to me how extensions are installed on Alpine. It seems to use `docker-php-ext-install` from what I can infer.

`Dockerfile` (I adopted this from somewhere):

```
RUN apk --no-cache add \
        freetype libpng libjpeg-turbo freetype-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev \
        wget \
        git \
        nginx \
        ca-certificates \
        supervisor \
        bash \
        nano \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        mysqli \
        pdo_mysql \
        opcache \
        ...
```

So, I tried

```
docker-php-ext-install soap
```

which told me `configure: error: xml2-config not found. Please check your libxml2 installation.` I tried a bunch of stuff, but

```
apk add --no-cache libxml2-dev
```

seemed to do something. I followed this again with `docker-php-ext-install soap`, which outputted

```
Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/
find . -name \*.gcno -o -name \*.gcda | xargs rm -f
find . -name \*.lo -o -name \*.o | xargs rm -f
find . -name \*.la -o -name \*.a | xargs rm -f
find . -name \*.so | xargs rm -f
find . -name .libs -a -type d|xargs rm -rf
rm -f libphp.la       modules/* libs/*
```

At this point, I did not run `make test`, as it's unclear where I'm suppose to go find this `Makefile`. I searched under `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/`, and `soap.so` was already there. Furthermore, my commands already enabled it for PHP-FPM. `php -i` showed `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-soap.ini,`.

I'm not entirely sure what I did. Is this (`docker-php-ext-install`) how you install extensions on this OS?

Answer (score 5):

The PHP SOAP extension requires the PHP XML extension, as documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/soap.requirements.php

I expect you need to install that first.

Presumably `docker-php-ext-install xml`.

You shouldn't need to compile the XML library yourself as it will be part of the extension.

Comment: What exactly is `docker-php-ext-install`, and is it specific to certain distributions of linux?

Comment: It's a command that's part of official PHP Docker Alpine images. See this repository: https://github.com/docker-library/php. You can see that it's doing stuff with `apk`, which is the package manager for Alpine Linux.

Comment: This answer will fail on an out-of-the-box Alpine install; you must first install `libxml2-dev` via apk for the the extension install to work, per the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is:

```
RUN set -ex && apk --no-cache add libxml2-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install soap
```

Comment: I had to run "apk update" first to prevent error.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a utility to your image using [this package](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer)

Example:

```
FROM php:7.2-cli

ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/master/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod uga+x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions gd xdebug
```

If you want, you can remove the last line and enter the container to play around with adding packages.

```
docker exec -it <container_id> bash                      # (swap bash for sh if using alpine)
```

Then you can just type `install-php-extensions <ext>`

Answer (score -1):

Not every alpine distribution contains docker-php-ext commands etc, and I don't know how to add them easily, it did not look simple at all to me.

Anyway, any php extension can be easily installed by issuing this alpine install command
to find any php extension

`apk search -v 'php' |grep ldap`

result

```
phpldapadmin-1.2.3-r4 - Web front-end for managing OpenLDAP
php7-ldap-7.2.22-r0 - PHP7 extension: LDAP
php5-ldap-5.6.40-r0 - ldap extension for PHP
```

to further install the extension, one must supply its name in a form without the suffix version part , eg. without `-7.2.22-r0` in `php7-ldap-7.2.22-r0` so it's `php7-ldap`
like this

`apk install php7-ldap`

Comment: docker-php-ext commands are NEVER a part of Alpine. They are a part of Docker. Though the OP did not specify it, this question is Docker-specific.

Comment: what makes you think I meant it oppositely from docker what OP and you meant?

When I repeat after OP's docker command doesnt mean I imply docker command is missing from non docker where its evident (so strictly speaking even meaning it its logically sound),but that its also only on a subset of 'dockers'

Just  because I suggested a solution that works on both docker and non docker?

Why to write 'Not every (DOCKER) alpine' instead of 'Not every alpine' for short, its you who says its evident from the question its docker based, so why I would reiterate word 'docker' along docker-php-ext?

Comment: @ZaneClaes fascinating you replied per se same 'apk' comment as me prior downvoting me - https://stackoverflow.com/q/48649837/3419535#comment135973312_48668565 'via apk for' ,right after comment referring docs that quasi refutes second part of your claim for alpine strictly speaking 'docker-php-ext commands are NEVER a part of Alpine' - https://stackoverflow.com/q/48649837/3419535##comment84361294_48668565  'docker-php-ext-install is a command that's part of official PHP Docker Alpine images' –
https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/8.1/alpine3.16/cli/Dockerfile#L10 refuted by code

Comment: You seem to be conflating Docker and Alpine. They are two entirely orthogonal ideas; the code you are linking to does not belong to either Docker or Alpine. Of course, when you run a Docker Alpine image you have this command because the command is a bridge between Docker and the Alpine OS. In other words, it is only present for the special docker PHP+Alpine distro. So the idea of having php-ext-install as a command in normal old Alpine (as you suggested) is entirely nonsensical. This also explains why, as you said, it is not always present — because its not actually a part of Alpine itself.

Comment: You did not address important part, addressed only the extremely residual marginal PS final notes that even didnt have to be there just informative which me myself marked flawed but from different view than you to begin with, the stuff what I wrote in the "dont use section" is not in some context complete, therefore the main part you didnt address the exact opposite of it of my response must be wrong . That part which I excluded was not exhausting not covering all the exclusive scenarios even those outside of the context of topic - unwitting strawman redhering  -negation of negation is confirm

Comment: @ZaneClaes will assume you dont want to intentionally hinder just to have "upper hind" be right,  that you genuinely think even when I once mentioned I/anyone normally wouldnt mean it, even if you/minority interpret it like that, that its almost impossible for Alpine dockers to miss docker-php-ext command. My experience and intent is that majority of dockers miss it, and I can prove you wrong on that front on the fly, if I construct alpine docker myself, please explain and elaborate how its going to contain that command , its not a docker core. Its plan B, backup, failsafe, fallback workaround